# What is the Hubbard-Holstein model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, lattice-model

Please explain as simply as possible what the Hubbard-Holtstein model is and what it is used for.

Answer (score 7):

The Hubbard-Holstein model is a electron-phonon model with Hamiltonian

$$ H ~=~ -t\sum_{i{\delta}\sigma}c^{\dagger}_{i\sigma}c^{}_{i+\delta\sigma}
        +U\sum_{i}n_{i\uparrow}n_{i\downarrow}  \nonumber +\omega_{0}\sum_{i}b^{\dagger}_{i}b^{}_{i}+g\sum_{i\sigma}n^{}_{i\sigma}(b^{\dagger}_{i}+b^{}_{i}).$$

Quoting R. Ramakumar, A. N. Das, *Polaron cross-overs and d-wave superconductivity in Hubbard-Holstein model,* [arXiv:cond-mat/0611355](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0611355),

> *Here $t$ ($>\,0$) is the hopping energy between molecules at lattice site
>   $ {i}\,$ and its nearest-neighbor lattice sites $i\,+\delta$,
>   $c_{i\sigma}$ ($c_{i\sigma}^{\dagger}$)
>   is the annihilation (creation) operator for the electron with spin
>   $\sigma$ at a lattice site $i$ and $n^{}_{i \sigma}$ is the corresponding number
>   operator, $U$ is on-site Coulomb repulsion,
>   $b^{}_i$ ($b_{i}^{\dagger}$) is the phonon annihilation 
>   (creation) operator, 
>   and $g$ is the interaction strength.*

The Hubbard-Holstein model a hybrid between the [Hubbard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard_model) (which has no electron-phonon coupling $g=0$), and the Holstein model (which has no Coulomb repulsion $U=0$).

See also p. 60 in the 2003 thesis  *Phonons, charge and spin in correlated systems* by Alexandru Macridin. The pdf file is available [here](http://dissertations.ub.rug.nl/faculties/science/2003/a.macridin/).

Comment: Please update the last link if you can. By the way, it looks to me that the Hubbard-Holstein model works for optical phonons only. Is there a similar model for acoustic phonons?

Comment: Do you know of any extension to the Hubbard-Holstein model which includes a phononic dispersion?